# Issue with Restful WebService

Tags: web-services, rest

my problem is the following:
When I test the access to a rest  webservice with web browser the web service answers well, however when I make a call from  a java  web application deploy under weblogic server it does not work: 
for the java Client I use the following code:

URL obj = new URL (url);
URLConnection con = (URLConnection) obj.openConnection ();

Someone can help me please :
That it is the difference between the two methods of invocation?

Comment: It could be many factors. Try to log the error message and the stack trace from the Java client and then post it here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here is the exception generated at the time of the call:
Java.io.IOException: Connection closed, EOF detected
Knowing that I use the https protocol

Comment: DId you try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java)? Also,  please try to use the solutions from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408507/connection-closed-eof-detected) and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245796/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh).